# Excel: why I can't see any values under watch

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new in Excel VBA and I'm trying to merge more Excel files into one.
Right now I selected a folder and I tried to see if I can see any variables under watch if I watch data (under comment read data from the file) and if I put a breakpoint at `filename = Dir`.
I can't see any data and I don't know why.

```
Public Sub Merge_files()
    On Error GoTo eh
    'Get the folder from the user'
    Dim folder As String
    folder = GetFolder()
    
    MsgBox (folder)
    
    
    'Read through the files in the folder'
    Dim filename As String, data As Variant
    filename = Dir(folder & ".xls")
    Do While Len(filename) > 0
        'read data from the file'
        Call ReadData(data, folder & filename)
        ' write data to the main worksheet'
        
        filename = Dir
    Loop
    Exit Sub
eh: MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub

Private Sub ReadData(ByRef data As Variant, ByVal currentFile As String)
    
    Dim book As Workbook
    Set book = Workbooks.Open(filename:=currentFile, ReadOnly:=True)
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = book.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    data = rg.Offset(1).Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1).Value
    book.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub

Public Function GetFolder() As String 
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) 
        .Title = "Select folder" 
        .Show 
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then 
            Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, "GetFolder()", "No folder was selected" 
        End If 
        GetFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator 
    End With 
End Function
```

Comment: What's code in `GetFolder()`? What does `any variables under watch` mean? `Local Windows` is used to check the variable in debugging.

Comment: This is getfolder:
Option Explicit

Public Function GetFolder() As String

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Select folder"
    .Show
    
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, "GetFolder()", "No folder was selected"
    End If
    GetFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
    End With
End Function

Comment: Does it break? you will see that it breaks if the line `filename = Dir` is dark red (same color as the breakpoint). If not maybe it doesn't find any files; also, as mentioned before, don't use `on error` when things aren't working as expected

Comment: At least one of your problems is that your `GetFolder` routine does return a `String` with the folder path, but `filename = Dir(folder & ".xls")` doesn't return a valid (wildcard) filename. I suggest added a check: `If Len(filename) > 0 Then` to make sure that `Dir` returns a valid filename.

Comment: Your call to Dir has no wildcard - `filename = Dir(folder & ".xls")` should be `filename = Dir(folder & "*.xls")` or even `"*.xls*"` if you also want xlsx files.

Comment: I fixed and wrote down filename = Dir(folder & "*.xls ) but it still doesn't work. Now I'm getting error: Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: Also I get error: runtime error 1004 on line:
data = rg.Offset(1).Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1).Value

Comment: Check what `rg` refers to - if it's already the whole sheet then you can't call `Offset(1)` on it.